# Change low battery notification from 10% to 20%? (High Sierra)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, high-sierra

Is it possible to change the native low battery notification alert from 10% of remaining battery to 20%?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any native ability to do this in macOS, but the the answers to this question: [Low Battery Alert for Mac OS X El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238037/low-battery-alert-for-mac-os-x-el-capitan) has some 3rd party app solutions which may do the trick. YMMV

Answer (score 2):

Check out this free app you can set up when to give a notification at which percentage also you can also add multiple percentage to notify you:https://github.com/codler/Battery-Time-Remaining/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using and highly recommend [Battery Medic](https://apps.apple.com/jp/app/battery-medic/id1438966058?l=en&mt=12)

It supports notifications based on a battery threshold that you can set. And it's completely free