# Scheduling a "sleep" event on Power Manager

Tags: battery, sleep-wake

I am using Mac OS El Capitan on my macbook pro and have just installed Power Manager following your recommendations elsewhere on this website (see [Low Battery Alert for Mac OS X El Capitan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/238037/low-battery-alert-for-mac-os-x-el-capitan)).

However, I see only an option to power down the computer when the battery charge falls below a specified level. I would like to simply display a pop-up warning on the screen along with a sound alarm and, if continued unheeded for a few minutes, put the laptop to sleep instead of powering down. I guess the way to achieve this would be a script; could you send me such a script indicating wherever I have to insert my preferred parameters? Thanks.

Comment: In the question above, I meant to say "...display a warning message with a sound alarm...." . I don't know if that is possible, but just in case it is....

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding a comment. While doing so please also add a link to the original question you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry, my first time on this site. I was trying to find a way to edit my post but couldn't find the edit option that is visible now. Anyway, I did edit the post, but don't see what needs to be linked, as the edit is in the text itself.

Comment: Ram, you mention "have just installed Power Manager following your recommendations elsewhere on this website.", adding the URL of this recommendations will make it easier to get the complete picture.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Patrix, I've added the URL and explained the edit as well this time. I'm learning!

Answer (score 1):

Below are the steps to creating an event to run an AppleScript when the battery level drops below 30%:

1. [Power Manager](https://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/) > File (menu) > **New Empty Event**;
2. Double-click new Untitled event to open in editor;
3. **Add a trigger** > Power Remaining > **Battery 30% Left**
4. **Add an action** > Run Script > **AppleScript**
5. AppleScript action > Cog > Edit
6. Copy and paste in the AppleScript below
7. **Apply** then **Save**

AppleScript to copy and paste into event:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
try
    with timeout of 10 seconds
        display dialog "Your battery has dropped below 30%" with icon caution buttons {"OK"} default button 1
        say "Low battery" 
    end timeout
on error -- likely timeout
    tell application "Finder" to sleep
end try
```

I wrote Power Manager. If you need support for Power Manager, please get in touch via [support@dssw.co.uk](https://www.dssw.co.uk/support/).

[image: Power Manager low power warning]